# smartcardio working only on 32 bit OpenJDK. acr122u

Tags: java, linux, nfc

I'm trying to start java application which reads info from nfc reader [acr122u](http://www.acs.com.hk/index.php?pid=product&id=ACR122U) on linux (ubuntu server).

I can access reader from utils like nfc-list. But:
TerminalFactory.getDefault().terminals().list().isEmpty() - always true on linux 64 and linux 32 + oracleJDK (1.7.45)
Only with OpenJDK 32 bits smartcardio works.